# LINQ - outer join to parent class in EF code first

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first, outer-join

I am missing something fundamental here I believe.

I have the following EF code-first entities: Company and Modem. A company can have a list of modems.

```
 public class Company
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        ...
        public virtual ICollection<Modem> Modems { get; set:}
    }  


 public class Modem
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        ...

    }
```

This generates a column `Company_ID` as a foreign key, on the `Modem` table.

I want to return all modems, with their company ID, if available. 
In SQL I would do the following :

```
select * from Modem m
left outer join Company c on 
m.Company_ID = c.ID
```

I am familiar with doing a left outer join in LINQ using .DefaultIfEmpty() in DB-first rather than code-first.

Where my confusion arises is that I don't have m.Company_ID available in LINQ to do the join, as it is auto generated by EF.

How do I perform this join in LINQ?

Comment: Why doesn't your `Modem` class have a reference to the `Company`?  Like `public Company Company { get; set;}`.

Comment: Have you tried something like... db.Companies.SelectMany(c => c.Modems) ? where db is your entity

Comment: @avi It sounds like some Modems are not linked to a company since the OP wants to left join to Company.

Comment: @juharr, correct. Some Modems are not linked to a company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real beauty of the EF is that you don't need to think of joins at all (well, most of the time). All you need is to properly define your entities and their relations via **navigation properties**. For instance, here is a definition of a model similar to yours:

```
public class Company
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Modem> Modems { get; set; }
}

public class Modem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Modem> Modems { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .HasMany(company => company.Modems)
            .WithOptional(modem => modem.Company)
            .Map(action => action.MapKey("Company_ID"));
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Note the `Company.Modems` and `Modem.Company` properties, and the fluent configuration of the relationship, including the name of the FK column.

Now, if we do the following

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    var query = db.Modems.Select(m => new { Modem = m, CompanyName = m.Company.Name });
    var sqlQuery = query.ToString();
}
```

the `sqlQuery` variable contains

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Company_ID] AS [Company_ID], 
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name1]
    FROM  [dbo].[Modems] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Companies] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Company_ID] = [Extent2].[ID]
```

And there you go - hope you see the `LEFT OUTER` join you were asking for.

Comment: The only thing to add is, that you need to be careful and check for null references, when accessing `Company` property.

In C# 5:
`var query = db.Modems.Select(m => new { Modem = m, CompanyName = m.Company == null ? string.Empty : m.Company.Name });`

In C# 6:
`var query = db.Modems.Select(m => new { Modem = m, CompanyName = m.Company?.Name });`

Comment: Great example. Navigation properties is the concept I was missing, as I incorrectly assumed these were created automatically.