# Null-safe navigation in Entity Framework Linq query

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

A customer has zero or one languages associated. I would like to do the following

```
db.Customer.Select(x => new {
     x.Id, x.Name, 
     Language = new { x.Language?.Id, x.Language?.Name }
})
```

But this doesn't even compile as linq expressions don't seem to know what to do with the null safe get operator (`?.`). How do I do the equivalent? I'd like the query generated to be a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `Language` and for the `Language` key to either be null, or an object with a null Id.

Comment: I am fairly certain that you need to give names to the left side of those anonymous objects, as in `new { id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }`. I am not sure if doing that will solve your `?.` issue.

Comment: @TravisJ nope, that has not been necessary for some time now. I don't think it ever was with anonymous objects.

Comment: have you tried like this: `Language = x.Language!=null? new { x.Language.Id, x.Language.Name } : new { 0, "" }` (i'm assuming it is an int and a string)

Comment: @CaioCésarS.Leonardi really? the LINQ provider knows how to decode that or are you just guessing?

Comment: sorry, i'm not really answering your question.

Comment: It does seem to generate a LEFT OUTER JOIN but if I bring in another entity similarly it does an INNER JOIN on that which doesn't really work for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use

```
db.Customer.Select(x => new {
     x.Id, x.Name, 
     Language = new { (int?)x.Language.Id, x.Language.Name }
})
```

which should generate SQL like this (of course table and column names could be different)

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Language_Id] AS [Language_Id], 
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name1]
    FROM  [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Languages] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Language_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
```

Here is another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547673/linq-outer-join-to-parent-class-in-ef-code-first/33551333#33551333) of a similar problem, take a look at the generated SQL.

**Update:** However, we need to include `T?` cast when projecting value type properties, otherwise the query cannot be materialized (`ToList()` fails with **InvalidOperationException**: *"Additional information: The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."*

**Update2:** Another option is to use this construct

```
db.Customer.Select(x => new {
     x.Id, x.Name, 
     Language = x.Language != null ? new { x.Language.Id, x.Language.Name } : null
})
```

The SQL looks like this

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[ID] IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 END AS [C1],
    [Extent1].[Language_Id] AS [Language_Id], 
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name1]
    FROM  [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Languages] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Language_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
```

and when materialized, will produce a **null** `Language` member (in constrast with the previous approach which produces instance with all members set to **null**)

Comment: yeah but add another similar entity in there `CustomerType = new { x.CustomerType.Id, x.CustomerType.Description }` and I can see in linqpad it's generating an inner join for that which will of course kill the row if there is no relavant `CustomerType`

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Well, what I posted (not here, the answer in the link) I tested in VS and get the sql string from there. Note the relation must be configured as optional. But you might have something different in mind?

Comment: Ah, you must be right - I have a `[Requred]` attribute on `CustomerType` doh! What happens when you ToList() - what is Language in the case it didn't match? Is it null or an empty object or what? I don't have the data at hand to test this out

Comment: @GeorgeMauer It sould be anonymous class instance (not null) with all fileds null. Ha, interesting question, for value types we might need to project `T?` into anonymous type.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Just tested, and yes - we need to project `T?`, otherwise ToList() throws runtime exception